# Side-by-side comparison of data by year in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I have table similar to the following:

```
Year | Product |  Value
2006   A          10
2006   B          20
2006   C          30
2007   A          40
2007   B          50
2007   C          60
```

I would like a query that would return the following comparison

```
Product | 2006 Value | 2007 Value
A         10           40
B         20           50
C         30           60
```

What are the options to do so? Can it be done without joins?

I'm working with DB2, but answers in all SQL types would be helpful.

Comment: Regarding the general part of your question in other DBMSs there is a `PIVOT` keyword

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select Product, 
    max(case when Year = 2006 then Value end) as [2006 Value], 
    max(case when Year = 2007 then Value end) as [2007 Value] 
from MyTable
group by Product
order by Product
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple cross tab query should do it

```
SELECT DISTINCT (year), PRODUCT,
sum (case when year = 2006 then VALUE else 0 end ) as [2006 Value]
sum (case when year = 2007 then value else 0 end ) as [2007 value]
from table
group by year, product
```

Check the syntax, but that's the basic idea. There is really no need to join.

Answer (score 3):

You've already got some answers that don't use a join, but just for comparison here's an alternative that does use a join:

```
SELECT
    T1.Product,
    T1.Value AS [2006 Value],
    T2.Value AS [2007 Value]
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.Product = T2.Product
AND T1.Year = 2006
AND T2.Year = 2007
```

> I'm working with DB2, but answers in all SQL types would be helpful.

Here's a solution using PIVOT that SQL Server supports:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    [2006] AS [2006 Value],
    [2007] AS [2007 Value]
FROM Table1
PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR Year IN ([2006], [2007]))
AS p;
```