# DB2 Convert rows to column

Tags: db2, pivot

I have to pivot the following data:

From:

```
SELECT NAMES, SUM(AMT1), SUM(AMT2) FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY NAMES

NAMES          AMT1        AMT2
Mike           6000        5000
Jerry          1000        10
King           500         2000
Mary           400         5000
Harry          100         500
```

to

```
Names Mike  Jerry  King  Mary  Harry
AMT1  6000  1000   500   400   100
AMT2  5000  10     2000  5000  500
```

Is it possible to implement this using queries on DB2? Note the NAME field is dynamic and I can have up to 25 rows on my table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fairly standard [pivot query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040680/side-by-side-comparison-of-data-by-year-in-sql), wherein most of the standard tricks work.  What are you using to _display_ this information?  You may have better luck just doing it in reporting.  Note that, unless you have a further query needing information in this format, this sort of pivot is actually a display problem, and may not belong in the database query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an already generic solution for this pivot problem. However, it is possible to use the DBMS_SQL to process the metadata and then perform the pivot.

I developed my own generic version of this pivot, and it is published in GitHub: https://github.com/angoca/db2tools

It takes a existing table (session or persistent) and creates a session table with the row as columns and vice versa.